# Element type is invalid: expected a string, really need help on this

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on a project with react native in expo was working fine when I was using sdk v32 , after upgrading to v34 then I got an error message saying

```
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

This error is located at:

```
in RCTView
in h
in RCTView
in _
in Explore
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t
in RCTView
in n
in RCTView
in t
in n
in p
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in RCTView
in u
in RCTView
in u
in C
in t
in n
in RCTView
in n
in RCTView
in u
in PanGestureHandler
in t
in n
in RCTView
in t
in t
in p
in r
in n
in App
in RCTView
in RCTView
in n
in n
in v
in RCTView
in RCTView
in c
```

This error is located at:

```
in n
in App
in RCTView
in RCTView
in n
in n
in v
in RCTView
in RCTView
in c
```

Android
iOS
Web

Comment: don't you have some code sample to share?

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was Expo have moved modules out of expo namespace.

```
import { AdMobBanner} from 'expo';
```

changed to

`import { AdMobBanner} from 'expo-ads-admob';`

and run

```
expo install expo-ads-admob
```